# How to Remove Whitespace Around Website Banner?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

There is a white border surrounding the banner of the website and it's really annoying me. It is like some sort of border about a width of 10px and white. This takes place at the top of the website.

I would have uploaded a picture, but it won't let me.

Anyways, this is all of the code for the banner:

```
.image{
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Is there any possible way I can remove this white border?

**Edit:**
I solved it by changing the image into a div and   making the image the background of the div and positioned it to left by 0 and top by 0.

Comment: If you don't want to use the image as a background and just an <img>, Im suspecting that you could also try `body{margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

try adding `border: 0 !important;`

Answer (score 0):

First thing first check image outer element if have any sort of padding margin or border, if yes then remove it otherwise jus give image width of 100vw instead of 100% .

Comment: Nothing outer is styled at all. I tried changing the percent but that didn't work.